# How to dynamically load images through a .png url with arguments (like Travis)

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to dynamically load images by php, similar to how it's done with Travis.

For example this

[image] is this https://api.travis-ci.org/travis-ci/travis-ci.png

And [image] is this 
https://api.travis-ci.org/travis-ci/travis-ci.png?branch=v3

As far as I understand there's some php logic on the server sides that takes the arguments and then chooses which images to show.

How do you get an image URL go through a .php script on the server side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way would be:

```
<?php
$image = 'default.png';
if ('foo' == 'bar') {
    $image = 'otherimage.png';
}
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($image);
?>
```

Now you can open the php file and you will get the image. If you want to have a file with a for example "png" extension, you could use the rewrite feature of your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can use mod_rewrite in .htaccess to rewrite .png files to getimage.php or something similar, passing the filename (travis-ci.png) as another get variable `getimage.php?name=travis-ci.png`.  Then the PHP file displays that image based on the value of `$_GET['name']` and the value of `$_GET['branch']` if it is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Directory /var/www/htdocs>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /var/www/htdocs

    RewriteCond $1.php -f
    RewriteCond $1.png !-f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*).png$ image.php?name=%2&%1
</Directory>
```

implement image.php for this requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The .png file is actually a file with PHP code that outputs a image/png header.

To make PHP interpret a .png file, you must change your webserver configuration accordingly.

Be careful though, you might not want to interpret *all* png files (specially if you accept file uploads).